# jQuery - Bold all the words in a query

Tags: jquery

I have a large HTML document, a book, and need to bold every occurrence of "Toronto".

How is this done in jQuery?

Comment: So what have you done so far? How do you want to find the occurence? In what type of DOM element it can be found in?

Comment: If it's a HTML document it may be sensible to do that with search and replace in a text editor instead of using JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: I found a plug in that does great replacements. https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-replacetext/raw/master/jquery.ba-replacetext.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bookPage = $("body");
bookPage.html(bookPage.html().replace(/Toronto/gi, '<strong>Toronto</strong>'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this on the server side. Searching through an entire "book" and replacing occurrences of DOM objects with other DOM objects (bold elements) is quite memory unfriendly.

If the book is presented as a page structure, I suggest doing the replacement only at the current page, and running the same replacement once the page is changed.

Comment: It's running as an application on an iPad, all local data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var book = $('#theBook');
var lookFor = 'Toronto';
book.html(book.html().replace(lookFor, '<strong>'+ lookFor +'</strong>');
```

But how well this scales to the length of a super long book, I have no idea.  But it should be fine for any reasonable amount of text shown on a single HTML page.